# Logical operators in switch case in c

Tags: c

I have a doubt using the logical operators in switch case. I tried this code online c compiler (www.onlinegdb.com).. My idea is to use || operator in the below case to evaluate if any one of the condition is true so that 'Karaikkal' will get displayed. But the compiler shows: 'Program finished with exit code 0'.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char code;
code = getc(stdin);
fflush(stdin);
switch(code){
    case ('K' || 'k'):
        puts("Karaikkal");
}

return 0;
```

}

```
 switch(code)
{//this code works, but I want to know how to use logical operator in switch.
case 'K':
case 'k':
  puts("Karaikkal");
  break;
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In summary: If the standard doesn't allow this explicitly, it's forbidden.

Comment: Okay thanks so much..

Answer (score 1):

It is a constant expression that is expected - and as you put it over there it is evaluated and as the ascii code of `k` is nonzero the result turns out to be `1` so you basically wrote `case 1:` which is not what you wanted.

You can't use an expression like that to determine that it is either `k` or `K`.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `'K' || 'k'`  is 1; it's a const expression. It is not an extension of "case" as in, say, SQL.